# How to filter by tags in gcloud python client

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-python

I am using gcloud python client library(https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client) to get a list of instances. I am able to use filters like name, status but I can't figure out a way to filter by tags. I am able to do that via gcloud cli tool.

Getting a list of machines works fine

```
instance_list = compute.instances().list(project=project,zone=zone).execute()
```

Even a filter by status works

```
instance_list = compute.instances().list(project=project,zone=zone,filter='status eq RUNNING').execute()
```

But, filtering by tags doesn't work

```
instance_list = compute.instances().list(project=project,zone=zone,filter='tags.items eq dev').execute()
```

It returns a HTTP Status 400.
But, using gcloud cli tool, I can succesfully run

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="tags.items=dev"
```

How can I manage to get this using the python client library?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the **gcloud compute instances describe** *instance-name* output for the instance you expect to match you'll see a relationship between the **tags** and **labels** attributes.  Many Google Cloud API resources, including compute.instances, support **labels**. They are a list of *name=value* pairs. For compute.instances each tag is also a label with an empty value.

--filter="labels.*name*:*" is the existence check for the label or tag *name*. The compute API filter equivalent is "labels.*name* eq '.*'".

For your specific example use the gcloud flag --filter="labels.dev:*" and/or the compute API filter="labels.dev eq '.*'".

You can also use the [Google APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/compute/v1/compute.instances.list) to play with compute.instances filter expressions.

Comment: I have been using network tags. That has been working great with terraform and ansible. So, if there's a way to continue with that, I'd prefer it. If not, I don't mind adding labels as well as long as it doesn't break my ansible scripts.

Comment: I also tried passing filter as "labels.dev eq '.*'" in API explorer. It gives a 200 OK but there are no items returned.

Comment: `gcloud compute instances list --filter="tags.items=dev"`

`gcloud compute instances list --filter="labels.dev:.*"`

The former gives me the list of machines with the dev tag. But the latter returns 0 items.

Comment: I recommended labels instead of tags because the --filter and API filter expressions are similar for labels.

Comment: I have a quote tag that appears in the labels value as: labels { "quote": "" }, and the API query "labels.quote eq '.*'" matches.  Does your labels value have a "dev": "" entry?

Comment: I have just added labels on my dev machines. Also, terraform didn't have support for labels till recently but they've added in a recent release else it would have been an additional overhead to do this. Trying with this now. Thank you.